# How to call public function inside mailable markdown template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

What I'm doing here is, I am inviting the users to the platform. So, basically I'm calling for a public function from the invitation model, which generates an invitation link based on the token. I am unable to set the link inside the button component of the markdown mailable template. As I cant call the `{{ $invitation->getLink() }}` inside the single quotes. Sorry for being a noob, please help me down here.

- Models/Invitation.php

```
public function generateToken() {
       $this->token = substr(md5(rand(0, 9) . $this->email . time()), 0, 32);
}

public function getLink() {
       return urldecode(route('register') . '?token=' . $this->token);
}
```

- views/mails/invitation-email.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => '{{ $invitation->getLink() }}'])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: `['url' => $invitation->getLink()]`

Comment: @lagbox That's what I wanted, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '{{ }}' attached to the URL like this

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $invitation->getLink()]) Button Text @endcomponent
```

I hope this help, you can get more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#generating-markdown-mailables